# Does a library function belongs to a process or task? (And arranging a function as a library function)

Tags: c, function, dynamic-library

This question may be vague, but I lack the information...

Let's say I am creating a project (writing in C). I have two tasks, A_task and B_task.

I need a function that will be called from both A_task and B_task. This will be a specific function (let's say func_A), therefore will work as a library function.

So, arranging the project files. I have two file lists: one for A_task and one for B_task. If I add the .c file which contains the func_A to the file list of the A_task, the function will be automatically belong to the A_task. (?)

After that, I will register the address of the func_A in a global function table in kernel space, so that the other tasks can call this function via the global function table.

My question is about the function belonging to a certain task. No matter how I arrange the global function table, it seems that the function that will be called belongs to a certain task. So B_task calls func_A via the global function table, but the func_A belongs to A_task, so will A_task wake up, for example?

Answer (score 1):

No.

Functions don't "belong" to tasks, or processes, or anything else in C. Especially since C doesn't have a standard concept of tasks or processes.

It's quite unclear exactly what you're doing, especially when you start talking about kernels and function tables.

Assuming a typical system, though, functions are just passive pieces of executable code. You can execute a function from one task, from all tasks, just as you please. If the function's name is visible from the code that runs in a particular task, that code can call the function and there's no magic able to prevent it by some "association" with a particular task.

Comment: Actually I am examining a custom-made embedded-system project which uses a so called "library system" as I tried to explain above. Until now I mindlessly used library functions, without thinking the mechanishm behind them. 

For what I need, we have bought a commercial library for some purpose. I will edit this library, include a "user" function call in it. But the library function that calls the user function will be called from different tasks. So I wondered in which task I can define this user called function. But I understand your answer verifies it doesn't matter where it is defined.